# Using Azure Servicebus queue with Camel in transactional mode

Tags: java, transactions, apache-camel, azure-servicebus-queues

I already setup a connection to an Azure Servicebus queue with camel-amqp successfully and could read messages from it. Then I tried to switch to transactional mode. This time, it fails with the following warning, which will be repeated every 5 seconds:
`c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'incoming' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: An AMQP error occurred (condition='amqp:internal-error'). [condition = amqp:internal-error]`

My route looks like this:
`from("amqp:queue:incoming?connectionFactory=#connectionFactory&transacted=true&transactionManager=#transactionManager")`.
The transactionManager is of type `org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager` and the (well configured) connectionFactory of type `org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`.

Could anybody imagine what is missing, maybe some additional configuration?

Comment: It seems, that it is not supported at the moment, I found a list of unsupported features and restrictions [on this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp), which contains the statement _Transacted sessions and distributed transactions are not supported_.